# Created docker container not running bash

Tags: docker

I have a docker container that is not running bash. My docker command to create container was:

```
docker run -it -d -p 8088:80 containername centos:centos6
```

Which pulls docker image centos6 from hub. Then run `docker start containername` and returns the name of the container, which is on this example, `containername`.

If I do `docker exec -it containername bash` it says Container xxxxxx is not running, When I check on my docker app, it is shaded grey. Rerun `docker start containername` then `docker ps -a` it says Container exited 1 second ago.

I read somewhere that the -d (detached mode) will keep the container running but in this case, it does not. This docker run was already used on my computer but I had to reformat due to circumstances. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your container fails to start

Comment: I run docker start containername and it does return my container name. If i rechecked docker ps -a, i can see my containername exited 1 second ago

Comment: so it ran then exited

Comment: that's what i meant

Comment: try to run it with bash directly:
docker run -it -d -p 8088:80 containername centos:centos6 /bin/bash
It will keep running and you will be able to connect

Answer (score 0):

Your container runs all commands and stop his life.
Try to create a Dockerfile with a sleep to keep it alive, like this:

FROM centos:centos6

CMD sleep infinity